# How to add custom message to Jest expect?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Image following test case:

```
it('valid emails checks', () => {
  ['abc@y.com', 'a@b.nz'/*, ...*/].map(mail => {
    expect(isValid(mail)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I would like to add auto-generated message for each email like `Email 'f@f.com' should be valid` so that it's easy to find failing test cases.

Something like:

```
// .map(email =>
expect(isValid(email), `Email ${email} should be valid`).toBe(true);
```

Is it possible in **Jest** ?

In Chai it was possible to do with second parameter like `expect(value, 'custom fail message').to.be...` and in Jasmine seems like it's done with `.because` clause. But cannot find solution in Jest.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to provide a message like that. But you could define your own [matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers).

For example you could create a `toBeValid(validator)` matcher:

```
expect.extend({
  toBeValid(received, validator) {
    if (validator(received)) {
      return {
        message: () => `Email ${received} should NOT be valid`,
        pass: true
      };
    } else {
      return {
        message: () => `Email ${received} should be valid`,
        pass: false
      };
    }
  }
});
```

And then you use it like this:

```
expect(mail).toBeValid(isValid);
```

Note: `toBeValid` returns a message for both cases (success and failure), because it allows you to use [`.not`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#not). The test will fail with the corresponding message depending on whether you want it to pass the validation.

```
expect(mail).toBeValid(isValid);
// pass === true: Test passes
// pass === false: Failure: Email ... should be valid

expect(mail).not.toBeValid(isValid);
// pass === true: Failure: Email ... should NOT be valid
// pass === false: Test passes
```

Comment: That's great thanks, one question - when using this in some file, it's local for that test file right ?
If I would like to have that function in some global should I use `beforeAll` then ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's only for the file, but if it's available throughout the test run, it probably depends on which file is executed first and when tests are run in parallel, that becomes a problem. But what you could do, is export the `toBeValid` function in a helper file and import it and register it with `expect.extend({ toBeValid })` wherever you need it.

Comment: Man, I'm not going to knock your answer, but I can't believe this is missing from jest matchers. This is a fundamental concept.

Answer (score 83):

You try this lib that extends jest: https://github.com/mattphillips/jest-expect-message

```
test('returns 2 when adding 1 and 1', () => {
  expect(1 + 1, 'Woah this should be 2!').toBe(3);
});
```

Comment: This is a very clean way and should be preferred to try & catch solutions.

Comment: This does not seem to be accurate with TS

Comment: This will fail: `expect()` takes at most one argument.

Comment: I am using this library with typescript and it works flawlessly

Comment: @Marc Make sure you have followed the [Setup](https://github.com/mattphillips/jest-expect-message#setup) instructions for `jest-expect-message`. Jest needs to be configured to use that module.

Comment: To work with typescript, make sure to also install the corresponding types

`npm i jest-expect-message @types/jest-expect-message`

Comment: You need to add this to your module.exports object in jest.config.js:  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-expect-message'],

Comment: Doesn't work with jest 27+. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mattphillips/jest-expect-message/pull/40) though.

Comment: This library hasn't been updated since 2018. Appears to be abandoned. Someone did create a drop-in replacement for it, though: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-27-expect-message

Comment: @Neeraj Looks like it closed 14 hours ago. "Fix is available in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expect-message/v/1.0.4"

Comment: That would be a nice solution, but sadly it doesn't work. It's type definitions are broken.

Answer (score 44):

I did this in some code I was writing by putting my `it` blocks inside `forEach`.

By doing this, I was able to achieve a very good approximation of what you're describing.

Pros:

- Excellent "native" error reports
- Counts the assertion as its own test
- No plugins needed.

Here's what your code would look like with my method:

```js
// you can't nest "it" blocks within each other,
// so this needs to be inside a describe block. 
describe('valid emails checks', () => {
  ['abc@y.com', 'a@b.nz'/*, ...*/].forEach(mail => {
    // here is where the magic happens
    it(`accepts ${mail} as a valid email`, () => {
      expect(isValid(mail)).toBe(true);
    })
  });
});
```

Errors then show up like this.

Notice how nice these are!

```
 FAIL  path/to/your.test.js
  ● valid emails checks › accepts abc@y.com as a valid email

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected: "abc@y.com"
    Received: "xyz@y.com"

      19 |    // here is where the magic happens
      20 |    it(`accepts ${mail} as a valid email`, () => {
    > 21 |      expect(isValid(mail)).toBe(true);
                                       ^
      22 |    })
```

Comment: I remember something similar is possible in Ruby, and it's nice to find that Jest supports it too.

Comment: I find this construct pretty powerful, it's strange that this answer is so neglected :)

Comment: How did the expected and received become the emails? isn't the expected supposed to be "true"?

Comment: Your solution is Josh Kelly's one, with inappropriate syntax. Use it.each(yourArray) instead (which is valid since early 2020 at least).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mozgor. Both approaches are valid and work just fine. The advantage of Josh Kelly's approach is that templating is easier with `test.each`. The advantage of my approach is that the code is much more flexible and intuitive. As a contrived example, each successive test's input can be derived based on the previous test, while still printing appropriate test failure messages. It's clean and workmanlike. I don't think 'inappropriate syntax' is a valid critique. Instead, we're just using a different approach with different pros and cons. There is no silver bullet.

Comment: As @ProblemsLoop pointed out, the `Expected` and `Received` examples don't make sense. All you get is `Expected: true\nRecieved: false`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer :( It's very sad to see everyone misusing the library

Answer (score 40):

Although it's not a general solution, for the common case of wanting a custom exception message to distinguish items in a loop, you can instead use Jest's [test.each](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout).

For example, your sample code:

```js
it('valid emails checks', () => {
  ['abc@y.com', 'a@b.nz'/*, ...*/].map(mail => {
    expect(isValid(mail)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Could instead become

```js
test.each(['abc@y.com', 'a@b.nz'/*, ...*/])(
    'checks that email %s is valid',
    mail => {
        expect(isValid(mail)).toBe(true);
    }
);
```

Comment: This is so cool. I didn't know about this API

Answer (score 19):

You can use try-catch:

```
try {
    expect(methodThatReturnsBoolean(inputValue)).toBeTruthy();
}
catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Something went wrong with value ${JSON.stringify(inputValue)}`, e);
}
```

Comment: This is solution is a bad idea, you can't make a difference when the tests failed because the return was false or  `methodThatReturnsBoolean` thrown an exception.

Comment: @dave008, yes both cases fail the test, but the error message is very explanatory and dependent on what went wrong.

Comment: @Marc you must have a problem with your code -- in the example there is only one parameter/value given to the `expect` function.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to add a custom error message is by using the `fail()` method:

```
it('valid emails checks', (done) => {
  ['abc@y.com', 'a@b.nz'/*, ...*/].map(mail => {
    if (!isValid(mail)) {
      done.fail(`Email '${mail}' should be valid`)
    } else {
      done()
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: done cannot be used for async tests, it gives error: Test functions cannot both take a 'done' callback and return something. Either use a 'done' callback, or return a promise.

Answer (score 8):

Just had to deal with this myself I think I'll make a PR to it possibly: But this could work with whatever you'd like. Basically, you make a custom method that allows the curried function to have a custom message as a third parameter.

It's important to remember that expect will set your first parameter (the one that goes into `expect(akaThisThing)` as the first parameter of your custom function.

For a generic Jest Message extender which can fit whatever Jest matching you'd already be able to use and then add a little bit of flourish:

```
expect.extend({
  toEqualMessage(received, expected, custom) {
    let pass = true;
    let message = '';
    try {
      // use the method from Jest that you want to extend
      // in a try block
      expect(received).toEqual(expected);
    } catch (e) {
      pass = false;
      message = `${e}\nCustom Message: ${custom}`;
    }
    return {
      pass,
      message: () => message,
      expected,
      received
    };
  }
});

declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
  namespace jest {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
    interface Matchers<R> {
      toEqualMessage(a: unknown, b: string): R;
    }
  }
}
```

Will show up like:

```
    Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 26
    Received: 13
    Custom Message: Sad Message Indicating failure :(
```

For specific look inside the expect(actualObject).toBe() in case that helps your use case:

```js
import diff from 'jest-diff'

expect.extend({
toBeMessage (received, expected, msg) {
  const pass = expected === received
  const message = pass
? () => `${this.utils.matcherHint('.not.toBe')}\n\n` +
        `Expected value to not be (using ===):\n` +
        `  ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}\n` +
        `Received:\n` +
        `  ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`
      : () => {
        const diffString = diff(expected, received, {
          expand: this.expand
        })
        return `${this.utils.matcherHint('.toBe')}\n\n` +
        `Expected value to be (using ===):\n` +
        `  ${this.utils.printExpected(expected)}\n` +
        `Received:\n` +
        `  ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}` +
        `${(diffString ? `\n\nDifference:\n\n${diffString}` : '')}\n` +
        `${(msg ? `Custom:\n  ${msg}` : '')}`
      }

    return { actual: received, message, pass }
  }
})
```

```js
// usage:
expect(myThing).toBeMessage(expectedArray, ' was not actually the expected array :(')
```

Comment: Great job; I added this to my setupTests.js for my Create-React-App created app and it solved all my troubles...

Answer (score 2):

I end up just testing the condition with logic and then using the `fail()` with a string template.

i.e.

```
it('key should not be found in object', () => {
    for (const key in object) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
        const element = object[key];
        if (element["someKeyName"] === false) {
          if (someCheckerSet.includes(key) === false) {
            fail(`${key} was not found in someCheckerSet.`)
          }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the fail() method was removed at some point https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11698

Answer (score 1):

you can use this: (you can define it inside the test)

```
      expect.extend({
ToBeMatch(expect, toBe, Msg) {  //Msg is the message you pass as parameter
    const pass = expect === toBe;
    if(pass){//pass = true its ok
        return {
            pass: pass,
            message: () => 'No ERRORS ',
          };
    }else{//not pass
        return {
            pass: pass,
            message: () => 'Error in Field   '+Msg + '  expect  ' +  '  ('+expect+') ' + 'recived '+'('+toBe+')',
          };
    }
},  });
```

and use it like this

```
     let z = 'TheMassageYouWantWhenErrror';
    expect(first.name).ToBeMatch(second.name,z);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@Zargold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348083/how-to-add-custom-message-to-jest-expect/#answer-45514619):

> For more options like the `comment` below, see [MatcherHintOptions doc](https://open-rpc.github.io/typings/interfaces/jest.matcherhintoptions.html)

```js
// custom matcher - omit expected
expect.extend({
  toBeAccessible(received) {
    if (pass) return { pass };
    return {
      pass,
      message: () =>
        `${this.utils.matcherHint('toBeAccessible', 'received', '', {
          comment: 'visible to screen readers',
        })}\n
Expected: ${this.utils.printExpected(true)}
Received: ${this.utils.printReceived(false)}`,
    };
  }
```

[image]

```js
// custom matcher - include expected
expect.extend({
  toBeAccessible(received) {
    if (pass) return { pass };
    return {
      pass,
      message: () =>
        `${this.utils.matcherHint('toBeAccessible', 'received', 'expected', { // <--
          comment: 'visible to screen readers',
        })}\n
Expected: ${this.utils.printExpected(true)}
Received: ${this.utils.printReceived(false)}`,
    };
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the value, I pass in a tuple with a descriptive label. For example, when asserting form validation state, I iterate over the labels I want to be marked as invalid like so:

```js
errorFields.forEach((label) => {
  const field = getByLabelText(label);

  expect(field.getAttribute('aria-invalid')).toStrictEqual('true');
});
```

Which gives the following error message:

```
expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1

      Array [
        "Day",
    -   "false",
    +   "true",
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @Monarch Wadia answer I created this function which takes a data object and a callback containing tests and then iterates this callback for each object item.

```js
function testDataSet(title, obj, func) {
  describe(title, () => {
    for (const k in obj) {
      test(`With data set: ${k}`, () => {
        func(obj[k]);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Usage

```js
testDataSet('My test case', { a: 'a1', b: 'b1' }, (data) => {
  expect(data).toEqual('a1');
});
```

Results

```
 FAIL  file.test.js
  My test case
    √ With data set: a (8 ms)
    × With data set: b (9 ms)

  ● My test case › With data set: b

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "a1"
    Received: "b1"

      102 |
      103 | testDataSet('My test case', { a: 'a1', b: 'b1' }, (data) => {
    > 104 |   expect(data).toEqual('a1');
          |                ^
      105 | });
      106 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the `expect` assertion to use `toThrow()` or `not.toThrow()`. Then throw an Error with your custom text. `jest` will include the custom text in the output.

```js
// Closure which returns function which may throw
function isValid (email) {
  return () => {
     // replace with a real test!
     if (email !== 'some@example.com') {
       throw new Error(`Email ${email} not valid`)
     }
  }
}

expect(isValid(email)).not.toThrow()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually using something like

```js
it('all numbers should be in the 0-60 or 180-360 range', async () => {
    const numbers = [0, 30, 180, 120];
    for (const number of numbers) {
        if ((number >= 0 && number <= 60) || (number >= 180 && number <= 360)) {
            console.log('All good');
        } else {
            expect(number).toBe('number between 0-60 or 180-360');
        }
    }
});
```

Generates:
[image]