# Jest: How to differently name a matcher

Tags: jestjs, matcher

I have a jest test that retrieves a list from my object under test and now I want to iterate over the list, checking that each entry meets certain conditions.

Like so:

```
test('mytest', () => {
  const underTest = ...
  underTest.doThisAndThat();
  expect(underTest.bla()).toBe('blub');
  ...
  const theList = underTest.getListOfDetails();
  for(const listElement of theList) {
    expect(listElement.hairColor).toBeDefined();
  }
});
```

When the test fails in the loop, jest will report that we expected 'defined' but got undefined.
But now I have to change the test code to find out which list element failed the condition.

My current approach is instead of using expect, throw an AssertionError, like so:

```
test('mytest', () => {
  const underTest = ...
  underTest.doThisAndThat();
  expect(underTest.bla()).toBe('blub');
  ...
  const theList = underTest.getListOfDetails();
  for(const listElement of theList) {
    if(typeof listElement.hairColor === 'undefined') {
      throw new AssertionError({
        message: theList.name + ' had no hairColor',
      });
    }
  }
});
```

While this works, I find this not very nice to code, especially when I have to check many conditions on the listElement.

So my question is: Is there a way to give the expect()... matcher a 'context name' easily?

A way that works is with the describe.each loop, however this structures the whole test differently in the way that I need to split up the test into two tests, one that tests single properties of the underTest object, and another that does the loop.

Unlike in [Is It Possible To Extend A Jest / Expect Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966914/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-jest-expect-matcher) , I would not want to write an expect.extend for each of these loops.